# Parsing nested JSON to CSV

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am trying to parse nested JSON to CSV, using XSLT transformation.
In this particular case each child object counting from "datasheet", e.g. "result-sheet"  and "balance-sheet", should end up in one CSV file (output) each. Currently I am however just elaborating getting out "result-sheet" only.

I noticed that the content of arrays are getting merged togehter.

**Data:**

```
<data>
{
  "datasheets": {
    "result-sheet": {"bank": [1,3], "credit": [2,6]},
    "balance-sheet": {"loans": [4,5], "inventory": [9,0]}
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
  >

<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->
    <xsl:template match="data">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <h2>Result sheet</h2>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="*/(string-join(head(*)/*/@key, ','), *!string-join(*, ','))" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
Result sheet
bank,credit
13,26
45,90
```

**Wanted result:**

```
bank,credit
1, 2,
3, 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand which data you want to have in each line, the following templates creates a line using `for-each-pair` on each pair of `fn:number` elements in the two `fn:array` children of the `fn:map` with the `@key` being `result-sheet`:

```
  <xsl:template match="*:map[@key = 'result-sheet']">
    <xsl:value-of select="for-each-pair(*:array[1]/*:number, *:array[2]/*:number, function($n1, $n2) { $n1 || ', ' || $n2 })"
      separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
```